# Function not getting executed in python

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have 2 functions`(recharge_list and sms_list)` in my below `Server()` class

```
import os
import json
import requests
import cherrypy
import ConfigParser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Server():

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):

        return "Seems Like You're Lost :D"


    @cherrypy.expose
    def recharge_list(self,carrier, state):
        details_array=[]
        small_details_array=[]
        price_cell_array=[]
        lst = []
        url = "link{}/{}".format(carrier,state)
        try:
            if self.t_arr.get(url) is not None:
                return json.dumps({'data': self.t_arr[url]})
        except AttributeError:
            self.t_arr = {}
        r  = requests.get(url)
        data = r.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
        table = soup.find('table',{'class':'table'})
        s=""
        detailtext = table.findAll('div',{'class':'detailtext'})


        for det in detailtext:
            details_array.append(det.text)

        smalldetails = table.findAll('div',{'style':'padding-top:5px'})

        for smallDet in smalldetails:
            small_details_array.append(smallDet.text);


        price_cells = table.findAll('td', {'class': 'pricecell'})
        for price_cell in price_cells:
            price_cell_array.append(price_cell.text)

        for i in range(len(details_array)):
            d_arr = {}
            d_arr['detail']=details_array[i]
            temp = small_details_array[i].split('\n')
            d_arr['talktime'] = temp[1] 
            d_arr['keyword']=temp[3]
            tempnew = price_cell_array[i].split('\n')
            d_arr['price'] = tempnew[1]
            d_arr['validity'] = tempnew[3]
            # global list
            lst.append(d_arr)
        self.t_arr[url] = lst
        return json.dumps({'data': self.t_arr[url]})

    @cherrypy.expose
    def sms_list(self,carrier, state):
        details_array=[]
        price_cell_array=[]
        lst = []
        url = "link/{}/{}".format(carrier,state)
        try:
            if self.t_arr.get(url) is not None:
                return json.dumps({'data': self.t_arr[url]})
        except AttributeError:
            self.t_arr = {}
        r  = requests.get(url)
        data = r.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
        table = soup.find('div',{'id':'SMS'})
        table2 = table.find('table',{'class':'table'})
        print(table2)
        s=""
        detailtext = table2.findAll('div',{'class':'detailtext'})


        for det in detailtext:
            details_array.append(det.text)

        smalldetails = table2.findAll('div',{'style':'padding-top:5px'})


        price_cells = table.findAll('td', {'class': 'pricecell'})
        for price_cell in price_cells:
            price_cell_array.append(price_cell.text)

        for i in range(len(details_array)):
            d_arr = {}
            d_arr['detail']=details_array[i]
            tempnew = price_cell_array[i].split('\n')
            d_arr['price'] = tempnew[1]
            d_arr['validity'] = tempnew[3]
            # global list
            lst.append(d_arr)
        self.t_arr[url] = lst
        return json.dumps({'data': self.t_arr[url]})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ''' Setting up the Server with Specified Configuration'''

    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',})
    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_port': int(os.environ.get('PORT', '5000')),})

cherrypy.quickstart(Server())
```

The problem is, when I run my server with `recharge_list` it works, but then I have to terminate my server from terminal and re-start the server to execute the `sms_list` function.

By my understanding the object once created by `Server` class is able to execute only the first called function.

What should I edit in my code such that I can execute the functions without terminating the server.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I run my server with `recharge_list`*"? Precisely, what actions do you take and what result do you observe?

Comment: I call the url in firefox http://localhost:5000/recharge_list/airtel/karnataka where http://localhost:5000/recharge_list/ is the base url and airtel/karnataka are arguments

Comment: And then what happens? Does that produce the expected result? Does it produce an error message? Do you visit http://localhost:5000/sms_list next? What leads you to believe that you must terminate your server?

Comment: After I visit the sms_list ....the old values which are shown by recharge_list are shown. I.e. the sms_list is not executed. Same for vice versa situation

Comment: Your conclusion is incorrect. Each function is being called when you invoke its  URL. The same results are returned because you cache the results in the `self.t_arr` dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By my understanding the object once created by `Server` class is able to execute only the first called function.

This is not so. Each time an HTTP request is provided, the web server calls the function associated to the URL of that request.

> What should I edit in my code such that I can execute the functions without terminating the server.

In `sms_list` (and **not** in `recharge_list`), replace every instance of `t_arr` with `t_sms_arr`.

Comment: i do not have t_url variable

Comment: Sorry, that was my typographical error. I meant `self.t_arr`.